# issue: dual selectlist moving all items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

below code is about dual selectlist. as shown in below image. 
[image]

Its working as desire. Only problem is, **if I click on last subject from Right hand side list box (select Subject list), it is moving all subject to left list box. Technically it should only move the clicked (selected) one subject.**

Any suggestion to resolve this?

Code is as following

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("eSchoolSystem")
        .directive('multiSelect',['$compile', '$log', multiSelect])

    function multiSelect($compile, $log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                name: '@',
                selectedModel: '=',
                availableModel: '='
            },
            /*template: '<select id="{{name}}-available" multiple ng-model="availableModel" ng-click="toSelected()" ng-options="a as a.subjectShortName for a in Model.available"></select>\n\n\
                        <select id="{{name}}-selected" ng-click="toAvailable()" multiple ng-model="selectedModel" ng-options="s as s.subjectShortName for s in Model.selected"></select>',
*/
            templateUrl:'app/class/html/dualMultiSelect.html',
            compile: function() {
                return {
                    pre: function($scope, $elem, $attr) {

                        var RefreshSelect = function(original, toFilter) {
                            var filtered = [];
                            angular.forEach(original, function(entity) {
                                var match = false;
                                for (var i = 0; i < toFilter.length; i++) {
                                    if (toFilter[i]["subjectId"] === entity["subjectId"]) {
                                        match = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!match) {
                                    filtered.push(entity);
                                }
                            });
                            return filtered;
                        };

                        var RefreshModel = function() {
                            /*$scope.selectedModel = $scope.Model.selected;*/
                            $scope.selectedModel = angular.copy($scope.Model.selected);
                            /*$scope.availableModel = $scope.Model.available;*/
                            $scope.availableModel = angular.copy($scope.Model.available);
                        };

                        var Init = function() {
                            $scope.Model = {
                                available: $scope.availableModel,
                                selected: $scope.selectedModel
                            };

                            $scope.selectedModel = [];
                            $scope.availableModel = [];

                            $scope.toSelected = function() {

                                $scope.Model.selected = $scope.Model.selected.concat($scope.availableModel);
                                $scope.Model.available = RefreshSelect($scope.Model.available, $scope.availableModel);
                                RefreshModel();
                            };

                            $scope.toAvailable = function() {
                                console.log("in here -x1")
                                console.log("x3-> " + JSON.stringify($scope.selectedModel))
                                $scope.Model.available = $scope.Model.available.concat($scope.selectedModel);
                                $scope.Model.selected = RefreshSelect($scope.Model.selected, $scope.selectedModel);
                                RefreshModel();
                            };

                        };

                        Init();
                    }
                };
            }
        };

    }

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `RefreshModel` function and updating selected values in `toSelected` and `toAvailable`:

```
$scope.toSelected = function() {
    $scope.Model.selected = $scope.Model.selected.concat($scope.availableModel);
    $scope.Model.available = RefreshSelect($scope.Model.available, $scope.availableModel);
    $scope.selectedModel = $scope.availableModel;
    $scope.availableModel = [];
};

$scope.toAvailable = function() {
    $scope.Model.available = $scope.Model.available.concat($scope.selectedModel);
    $scope.Model.selected = RefreshSelect($scope.Model.selected, $scope.selectedModel);
    $scope.selectedModel = [];
    $scope.availableModel = $scope.selectedModel;
};
```

Comment: Thank for suggestion, I tried your suggestion, but now it throwing error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" when clicked on last item. it stucked on for (var i = 0; i < toFilter.length; i++) {....

Comment: Replace `null` with `[]`

Comment: I cannot set to empty, because I need selected subject list for submit purpose.    if I set to [] then     selected: $scope.selectedModel ... $scope.selected become empty too.